# LuaLaTex/XeLaTex with KOMA for Cyrillics

Tags: xetex, luatex, koma-script, cyrillic

How can I use LuaLatex/XeLaTex with KOMA-script for Cyrillics?
When I try to write:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{А.В. Тор}
\title{Великий об'єм }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Перший}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

I get a lot of errors
`Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrill(polyglossia) Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is indeed far from clear, but the issue is that there's no coverage of Cyrillic in the default *sans serif* font.

Note that `scrartcl` uses sans serif font for the titles, by default. So you need to set a Cyrillic font also for sans serif, naming it `\cyrillicfontsf`.

A similar problem would raise also for the typewriter type family: set `\cyrillicfonttt` for it.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{CMU Sans Serif}[Script=Cyrillic]

\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}

\begin{document}
\author{А.В. Тор}
\title{Великий об'єм }
\maketitle
\section{Перший}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]