# Overleaf's polyglossia package with Cyrillic fonts

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, overleaf, cyrillic

I am currently trying to use Cyrillic fonts in overleaf, but whatever I try overleaf throws an error, though PDF preview looks fine.

My preambule code looks like:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{ukrainian}
\setotherlanguages{english,russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Liberation Mono}
```

As already proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91507/liberation-mono-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-cyrillic-script) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413775/error-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-cyrillic-script).

Nevertheless, overleaf give me and error:

```
Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font LiberationMono(0) does not contain the "Cyrillic" script!

(polyglossia)                Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily command.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \selectlanguage *{ukrainian}

This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

Is there a workaround to solve this problem in overleaf? Is it happen because overleaf uses old version of polyglossia or it is a problem with the package itself? Can it be reported to the people for a fix?

Comment: you only defined a tt-font for cyrilic. Define also `\cyrillicfont` and `\cyrillicfontsf`.

Comment: I built the LiberationMono fonts from the source on GitHub and they do have the Cyrillic script. In other words, I can't reproduce the issue with an up-to-date version of the fonts.

Comment: Thanks very much! Adding \cyrillicfont and \cyrillicfontsf fonts solved the problem.

Comment: Also helped me!