# Cyrillic, Palatino, and xelatex

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, cyrillic

I want to write a text in russian in Palatino(-like?) font, using polyglossia and xelatex. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with any variety of free Palatino-like fonts.  My example below uses my own typeface ([Tex Gyre Parliamentary](https://github.com/ezgranet/tg-parl), which is Palatino with different quotation marks), but the cyrillic characters in Tex Gyre Parliamentary are simply copied over from D [B Miller's Domitian](https://github.com/dbenjaminmiller/domitian/releases/tag/1.0.1), which is also freely available under the same open licence.  With this, and using Babel or Polyglossia, you can simply type in Russian, as normal. See this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Parliamentary}
\begin{document}
    Привет
\end{document}
```

[image: cyrillic]

Comment: https://dpaste.org/AWTN «Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font TeXGyreParliamentary(1) doe s not contain the "Cyrillic" script!»

Comment: @Danya Very strange as I can't reproduce that error — which version of the typeface did you download? https://imgur.com/a/94P4hkh

Comment: Try this https://dpaste.org/VwrF

Comment: @Danya This is a well known issue with `polyglossia` —my suggestion is to use `babel`.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91507/liberation-mono-the-current-roman-font-does-not-contain-the-cyrillic-script

Answer (score 1):

There are Cyrillic letters in Palatino Linotype, which comes with Windows.

Some older versions of [TeX Gyre Pagella](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/TeX-Gyre-Pagella) have Cyrillic characters that have since been removed, but you can download them into a subdirectory of your project folder and load them with `Path=`.

Comment: I use GNU/Linux.

Comment: @Danya OK, I added a free alternative.